# Total size of page tables vs page table size

Tags: memory, virtual, paging

I am given a virtual memory system with **32 bit addresses**

I have 2 scenarios, one using a **pure paging system** and another using a **two-level paging system**

I am asked to determine the "What is the page
table size if the page size is: 1KB, 4KB, 1MB?"

*1kb:* 2^32 / 2^10 = 2^22

*4kb:* 2^32 / 2^12 = 2^20

*1MB* 2^32 / 2^20 = 2^12.

I can then determine the memory size by taking 4*the page table size for each answer respectively.

The second scenario gives me:

**two-level paging**  The First level page level table has 1024 entries. What is the total size of the page tables for a page size of a) 1K b) 1 M

is the total size of the page tables the same as the size of the page table?  if not can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no answer to that given the data you have supplied.

Comment: @user3344003 what more info is required I am only given that

Comment: The size of the page table is governed by system parameters, the layout of the logical address space, and process quotas; none of which you have specified.